# How to Show R Crosstable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

my server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$table0 <- renderPrint({
  confusionMatrix(sms_results$predict_type,
                  sms_results$actual_type, positive = "spam")
})

output$table <- renderDataTable({
  table(sms_results$actual_type, sms_results$predict_type)
})
output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
  CrossTable(sms_test_pred, sms_test_labels,
             prop.chisq = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.r = FALSE,
             dnn = c('predicted', 'actual'))
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Evaluating Model Performance"),


  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    column(12,
           dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  ),
           dataTableOutput('table0')

 )
    )
```

So, how to external view Crosstable and confusion matrix in shiny?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Is this (a) about how to display tables in shiny or (b) about how to get data into shiny or (c) about the CrossTable confusionMatrix functions? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on how to ask good questions and to supply a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: If you are using `renderDataTable`, it needs to be a `DT` object. You can use `datatable(whatever_other_table_object_you_have)`. Take a look at the documentation perhaps.

Comment: how to show it on web in external view, im confused too cause it was not a table, but a xtable...

Comment: no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "Confusionmatrix" error was something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presuming all global variable loaded and library, runapp with this code
`uir.r`

```
library(shiny)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      # Application title
      titlePanel("Machine Learning - Evaluating Model Performance"),
      br(),br(),

      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          h2("Davin", align = "center"),
          h2("(>..<)", align = "center", style = "color:blue"),
          img(src = "40.png", height = 150, width = 300,style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;")
        ),

      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot"),
        column(12,dataTableOutput('table')),

        h2("Kappa Table", align = "center"),verbatimTextOutput('tabkapp'),

        h2("xTable", align = "center"),verbatimTextOutput('table1'),

        h2("ROC prob", align = "center"),
        column(12,dataTableOutput('tables'))
    ))))
    #  column(12,tableOutput('tables'))
```

with verbatimtextoutput seems can show this `server.r`

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$table1 <- renderPrint({
  ctab <- CrossTable(sms_test_pred, sms_test_labels,
             prop.chisq = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.r = FALSE,
             dnn = c('predicted', 'actual'))

})
    output$tabkapp <- renderPrint({
          tbkp <- Kappa(table(sms_results$actual_type, sms_results$predict_type))
          tbkp
        })
        })
```

to web external view

[output in web external view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oYl3.png)

[output in web external view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Ery.jpg)

any way to make it better ? its on ascii style (i think)... i want it like "datatableoutput" 
i am okay